# How to obtain the unique count of a field of the entire data view in Table in Elastic Search Kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have some data in Elastic Search and the records are like

```json
{
    {
        "name": "Alice",
        "fruit": "apple",
        "time": "13:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alice",
        "fruit": "apple",
        "time": "14:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alice",
        "fruit": "banana",
        "time": "15:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "fruit": "apple",
        "time": "13:00"
    },
}
```

I created a table in the dashboard to show the unique number of fruit each person had and it looks like:

| Name | Unique count of fruit |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 2 |
| Bob | 1 |

Now I would like to know the portion of fruit each person had among all known fruits. That is to say, I would like to have a table like this:

| Name | Unique count of fruit | Portion of fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 2 | 1 |
| Bob | 1 | 0.5 |

Thus, I will need a unique count of fruits among all records.

I tried by adding a metric in my table and set the formula as

```
unique_count(fruit) / overall_sum(unique_count(fruit))
```

However, `overall_sum` just adds up the values of unique counts in each row and gives me a table like:

| Name | Unique count of fruit | Portion of fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 2 | 0.67 |
| Bob | 1 | 0.33 |

The unique count in each row is not mutually exclusive so we cannot simply add them up. However, the formulae given in the dashboard table seem either row-wise or column-wise and thus I did not find a way to obtain the unique count of the entire data view.